# Upstart script - how to log errors

Tags: upstart

After lot of googling, I have managed to create this service script placed in `/etc/init/service.conf`. It works fine but some time it stops. I want to find out a way to record only errors why it stopped. So I can know what is the issue with my script.

Usage of this script is to listen custom port on my server and receive gps data from the device.

My question is how can only log the error message and not everything. I am running on VPS with Ubuntu LTS 14.04.

```
description "GPS Data connection"
Author "Dharmesh Patel"
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn
respawn limit 99 5
script
export HOME="/httpdocs"
exec /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/php_file.php
end script
```

Any help would be greatfull. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An error is going out on the stderr output. So you if you want to log it you have to redirect it's output into a file.

e.g.

`php myscript 2>myscript-err.log`

stdin, stout and sterr are handled by the shell through some variables as in stdin is 0, stout is 1 and stderr is 2. So if you want to redirect anything of those you use either variable to do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. How can I pipe output? `code` exec /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/php_file.php | /var/log/service.log

Comment: It would be literally what I wrote `exec /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/php_file.php 2>/var/log/service.log`

Comment: Thank  you once again. What does this 2> means? Is it type of error being recorded or something else?  I just want to log the errors so system/server will not run out of space.

Comment: Added it to the answer. 2 means only error codes, 1 is the default output what your script would write.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will update my script and post the results. Once again thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Thanks for you response. What I have found out is that if there is an error in my php_file, it's not going to record any errors because the connection will be closed and there will be some information recorded in /var/log/messages. So I will use >> /var/log/service.log >2&1 to log everything. But I will need to find a way to delete  certain days old log files.  Any idea how can I always run my service in the event of system crash, reboot, or anything? Thanks a lot.